# How to use WORKDAY with month and not days

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I would like to use `WORKDAY` in order to skip week-end. The issue I am facing is that `WORKDAY` is structured as follow :

```
=WORKDAY(startdate,**number of days** ,1)
```

**I don't want to use a number of day** but a number of month.
The basic formula I use is the following one (but it does not dodge week end) :

```
=EDATE(DATE,12)
```

Reproducible example :

```
   =EDATE("12/21/2022",1) = 01/21/2023 'WEEK END : The excepted output is 01/23/2023
```

I TRIED :

```
=WORKDAY(EDATE("12/21/2022",1),0,1)
```

But it keep returns me 01/21/2023

So, how do I add month to date and to dodge week end if needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both formulae & tweak your approach a little bit to get the desired results. Assuming input date is in cell `A2`

`=WORKDAY(EDATE(A2-1,1),1)`

We subtract 1 day from original start date to compensate for the 1 day jump that comes from `WORKDAY` formula.

Comment: @JvdV, I liked your previous version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
=WORKDAY(A1,NETWORKDAYS(A1,EDATE(A1,1),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=WORKDAY(Startdate,EDATE(Startdate,NoOfMonths)-Startdate)
```

E.g. with your start date in RC[-2] and the number of months in RC[1], this would work:

```
=WORKDAY(RC[-2],EDATE(RC[-2],RC[-1])-RC[-2])
```

But what you maybe want is the number of working days between Startdate and a date x calendar months after Startdate? In that case you should use NETWORKDAYS instead.

```
= NETWORKDAYS(StartDate,EDATE(Startdate, NoOfMonths))
```